# How to configure to use replicaset of mongodb inside the app.properties of GKE configMap

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, configmap

We have GKE Cluster and the mongoDB replicaset is running from outside of the k8s cluster and we have registered the DNS for the mongo nodes inside the GCP DNS. We are using configMap to pass the details of MongoDB like host, port, username, password, etc. to connect to MongoDB primary and secondary nodes.
Initially, we have hardcoded a mongodb primary node DNS inside the variable as:
`"mongodb.primary.host=mongo-node-1.abc\n mongodb.primary.port=27017\n mongodb.primary.username=xyz\n mongodb.primary.password=..."` inside the app.properties inside the configMap and the application runs fine. The issue arises whenever the MongoDB tries to switch between the replicaset in case of failure in mongo-node-1 then the pod breaks with an error that it cannot understand the name inside the "`mongodb.primary.host=mongo-node-1.abc`".
So, the challenge is to figure out how to pass the replicaset of mongoDB inside the variable "`mongodb.primary.host=`" inside the app.properties inside the configMap.

We know that `uri` can be used instead of `host` but we need to figure out how to perform this task using the `host` only. I have tried to use a syntax as:

`"mongodb.primary.host=mongo-node-1.abc,mongo-node-2.abc,mongo-node-3.abc\n mongodb.primary.port=27017\n mongodb.primary.username=xyz\n mongodb.primary.password=..."`

but didn't worked and failed with the error :

```
2023-07-04 09:52:05.817 UTC {logLevel=ERROR}[main] org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoBatchConfigurer': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mongoExecutionContextDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongoExecutionContextDao': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=mongo-node-1.abc,mongo-node-2.abc,mongo-node3.abc:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: mongo-node-1.abc,mongo-node-2.abc,mongo-node3.abc}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: mongo-node-1.abc,mongo-node-2.abc,mongo-node3.abc}}]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:410) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar!/:5.3.18]
```